# I met a problem when I coding assembly language, my code can't end

Tags: assembly, x86-16

here is my code

```
ASSUME cs:code,ds:data,ss:stack
data SEGMENT
ENDS
stack SEGMENT
    db 10 dup(0)
ENDS

code SEGMENT
start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,stack
    mov ss,ax
    mov bx,19

    call output

    mov ah,4CH  
    int 21H 

output proc
    mov cx,0
    mov ax,bx
    mov bx,10

division:  
    div bx
    push dx
    inc cx
    cmp ax,0
    jne division

    ret 
output endp

code ENDS
end start
```

I use the debug to find the mistake in my code.
I found that when ax = 0001,bx=000A and I invoke div bx , the ax became E666，I don't kown why it happen , it confused me.
[image]

Comment: Please note that the [tag:assembly] tag specifically requests that you add processor and assembler tags also. Whilst I may assume that this is x86 or x64, why should I guess when you *know*?

Comment: You're leaving the remainder in DX, where the next `div` uses it as the high half of the dividend, creating an infinite loop for numbers that aren't a power of the divisor or something like that.